# How to update multiple table at once using TypeORM

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM with NestJS and I want to do this query to a MySQL DB:

```sql
UPDATE user u, table2 t2
SET u.is_active = 0, t2.is_active = 0
WHERE u.id = 'id'
AND t2.user_id = u.id;
```

Relations are:

`User`:

```js
@OneToMany(
    () => Table2,
    (t2) => t2.user,
    {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        eager: true
    }
)
field_table_2: Table2[]
```

And `Table2`

```js
@ManyToOne(
    () => User,
    (user) => user.field_table_2
)
@JoinColumn({name:'user_id'})
user: User
```

The point is: One user can have many `table2` but every row in `table2` depends for only one user. Then a relation `one-to-many` and `many-to-one`. All right so far.

When I delete one user, I don't want remove the data into DB, I want to set field `is_active` to false in both tables.

I can do it in a single query using SQL but using TypeORM I've only found a solution using raw sql:

```js
async remove(id: string) {
    return await this.dataSource.query(`
        UPDATE user u, table2 t2
        SET u.is_active = 0, t2.is_active = 0
        WHERE u.id = ?
        AND t2.user_id = u.id`,[id])
        
}
```

But having an ORM I don't like to use raw SQL... how can I get the query I want using the ORM?

I know I can create a transaction, update first one table, then the other table and if everything is ok commit the transaction.

But, if I can do it in a single query, is efficient to do it in a transaction? I refer also for simplicity in a single query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

TypeORM does not currently have an expressive way of updating multiple tables in a single query this via either query builder or repository methods. Currently those are limited to updating a single table.

I would say in your case, if you wish to do this in a single query pull out isActive into an entity / table of its own. Then both user and table 2 could have a 1-1 relationship with this new entity. Therefore, you only need to update one table entry.

Otherwise, this can be done with two separate update queries and a transaction. How you will perform the update is more a matter of choice, could use Repository or QueryBuilder.

There are also several options for [managing transactions](https://typeorm.io/transactions), the most fine grained of which is QueryRunner.

Pseudocode might look something like this:

```
queryRunner.startTransaction();
try {
    await  queryRunner
       .createQueryBuilder()
       .update(EntityA)
       .set({isActive: false})
       .execute();

    await queryRunner
       .createQueryBuilder()
       .update(EntityB)
       .set({isActive: false})
       .execute();

    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
}
catch (e) {
    queryRunner.rollbackTransaction()
}
```

However, I suspect that this could all also be done using CASCADE and [softDelete](https://typeorm.io/delete-query-builder#soft-delete)